# Create a second (virtual) monitor Windows 10 1909

Tags: windows, display, teamviewer

I would like to add a second monitor without plugging one, to use another computer as a second screen through TeamViewer. I used Win+P before, but since the update of Windows 10, it doesn't work anymore and I can't add manually a display in Settings.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried putting the second TeamViewer screen on another (virtual) desktop and switching back and forth that way?

Comment: I do not really understand what you are suggesting. Could you more specific, please? What I try to do is to create another monitor on the host, and use the guest computer as a second screen, by displaying the second screen on the guest with TeamViewer.

Comment: What I am suggesting is using the virtual desktops built into windows to run your team-viewer instance in a "separate space".  If you are still left puzzled, look up [windows 10 virtual desktop](https://community.windows.com/en-us/stories/virtual-desktop-windows-10)..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't seem to work. Indeed, I don't know if there is a parameter to change, but, by default, TeamViewer is not limited in one virtual desktop. If I switch to another desktop on the host, TeamViewer changes too on the guest.